# Re-partition to install MacOS Catalina

Tags: partitioning, macbook-pro, macos-catalina

During the latest update, I was stuck in a boot loop. It was saying there was not enough space.

Then I tried to boot from the Macintosh HD but it was always stuck after pressing Restart.

After that I did a forced shutdown and want to reinstall MacOS Catalina but cannot as it is showing I don't have enough space.

So, I want to format/re-partition and install but there are 2 APFS volumes now, "Macintosh HD" & "Macintosh HD - Data". What is the best way to do this without further messing up?

Answer (score 0):

After much trying, I ended up erasing "Macintosh HD" and reinstalled MacOS Catalina.

Much to my surprise, there were two "Macintosh HD - Data" after installation was completed.

The old "Macintosh HD - Data" had all my user data. I just had to copy & paste to backup what I needed and erase that one to cleanup the machine.